# User How can I grab the CAPTCHA image that changes every time it is reloaded or when I send a GET request,without taking a screenshot?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium-webdriver, captcha, webautomation

I have a CAPTCHA on a login page and I want to capture that CAPTCHA using **Selenium, javascript** or **any other possible method**.
The CAPTCHA element is displayed as

```
<img src="https://rds3.northsouth.edu/index.php/captcha">.
```

However, the CAPTCHA image changes every time I reload or download the CAPTCHA from the link: https://rds3.northsouth.edu/index.php/captcha

how can I get the exact image that is displayed ad it is on the page?

I tried using the following code to grab the CAPTCHA image:

```
captcha_img = chrome_driver.find_element_by_xpath('//img[@id="captcha-img"]')
captcha_img_url = captcha_img.get_attribute('src')
response = requests.get(captcha_img_url)
if response.status_code == 200:
    # Save the image to a file
    with open('captcha.png', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(response.content)
```

However, this method does not work because the CAPTCHA image changes every time a new request is sent, and the link provides a new CAPTCHA image. But I want to capture the displayed image for OCR purposes **without taking a screenshot of the element**. *So how can i get the exact image that is displayed ad it is on the page?*

Answer (score 0):

You can use pytesseract and opencv.
The flow is
Open it in selenium
Find the captcha image on screen
Take screenshot
Save and read it again and use CV and pytesseract to decode it. 8 out of 10 captchas can be captured if they are simple.
Then pass the text to captcha textbox

```
captcha = driver.find_element('id','imgcapcha')    
captcha_image = captcha.screenshot_as_png
captcha_image = captcha.screenshot_as_png
with open('d:\\captcha1.png', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(captcha_image)     
imgcaptcha=mpimg.imread('d:\\captcha1.png')
aa=imgcaptcha*255
aa=aa.astype('uint8')
gry = cv2.cvtColor(aa, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
(h, w) = gry.shape[:2]
gry = cv2.resize(gry, (w*2, h*2))
clsimg = cv2.morphologyEx(gry, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, None)
thr = cv2.threshold(clsimg, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
txt = pytesseract.image_to_string(thr)
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's how can achieve that

```py
from PIL import Image
import requests

captcha_img_url ="https://rds3.northsouth.edu/index.php/captcha"
img = Image.open(requests.get(captcha_img_url, stream=True).raw)
img.show()
img.save("captcha.png")
```

Each time you run this script, it'll fetch & show the new dynamic image and can cross-verify it with the saved `captcha.png` image.

install the used libraries:

```
pip install requests
pip install Pillow
```

Comment: you need to take screenshot of that image then save it and then use your captcha reading package, look at the answer given above again pasting the link https://stackoverflow.com/a/77864149/8170619